# Basic Auth in multiple directories on same virtualhost

Tags: linux, configuration, apache-2.4, httpd, http-basic-authentication

Is it possible to nest basic auth? So that the parent folder and all subfolders can be accessed using one basic auth directive but subfolders have seperate auth

**VHost config:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName subdomain.domain.com
        #
        #       Comment
        #
        ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/analytics_prox_error_log"
        CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/analytics_prox_access_log" common
        SSLProxyEngine on
        SSLProxyVerify none
        ProxyRequests Off

        <Location />
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "ProxyMain"
                AuthUserFile /var/www/analytics-auth/.htpasswd
                Require user datateam
                Satisfy any
                Deny from all
                Allow from 192.168.0.0/16 10.0.0.0/8
        </Location>

        <Location /folder1/>
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Proxy"
                AuthUserFile /var/www/analytics-auth/.htpasswd
                Require user mainuser folder1user
                Satisfy any
                Deny from all
                Allow from 192.168.0.0/16 10.0.0.0/8
        </Location>

        <Location /anotherfolder/>
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Proxy"
                AuthUserFile /var/www/analytics-auth/.htpasswd
                Require user mainuser anotherfolderuser
                Satisfy any
                Deny from all
                Allow from 192.168.0.0/16 10.0.0.0/8
        </Location>

        ProxyPass / https://1.1.1.1/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://1.1.1.1/
</VirtualHost>
```

The basic auth that is prompted for / is the same for all the sub folders and works correctly. (AuthMain) However if I browse to a specified folder such as folder1 i get the root basic auth and not the basic auth specific to that location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a lack of quotes around the folders in Location. Adding double quotes around them resolved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location) on the `<Location>` directive, the first `Location` directive matches all the other paths too. Since you are using Apache 2.4, you should be able to use negative matches with `LocationMatch`. Something along

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?!anotherfolder|folder1)">
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This had crossed by mind as i know vhosts act similarly. How come when I try the <Location /> at the bottom this is applied over all the others?